# Coloring odd rows for multiple tables

Tags: jquery, html

If I have more than one table on a page, and I try coloring the odd rows, jQuery seems to merge the entire group of TRs (from all tables) together when it does its determining of which rows are odd.

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/ryjennings/KNmuQ/5/

Is there a way to stop jQuery from doing this and treat each table separately?

Comment: Just an FYI - CSS3 can do this, though it doesn't work in <=IE8. Use `tr:nth-child(odd) td`. Here's a full list of supported browsers: http://caniuse.com/css-sel3

Comment: In modern browsers you can do this with pure CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/KNmuQ/22/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table").find("TR:even").addClass("odd");
});
```

Basically, your original selector was grabbing a group of all of the `tr` elements contained within `table`elements on the page, which was all of them, and then taking every other one of that huge set. The new series of selectors first creates a group of all the tables and then a sub group of the rows within each table and then takes every other one of the rows in each sub group.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using Javascript for anything that you can do with CSS. CSS is orders of magnitude faster. What you need is the [`:nth-child` psudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3anth-child):

```
tr:nth-child(odd) { background:#f5f6f8; }
```

[See Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/anstosa/KNmuQ/19/)

Comment: For the record, I definitely agree with you. My answer was simply a response to the request to correct the jQuery snippet and not necessarily a recommendation to use jQuery instead of CSS or vanilla JavaScript. However, it should be noted that nth-child is not supported in some still-very-common browsers (including IE 8 and below).

Comment: Both of our answers + ]Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) are the ideal cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you could do it:

```
$("table").each(function(){
    $("tr:even", this).addClass("odd");
});
```

Comment: Eh, no need for `.each()` here.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL well... if I was using the find method, perhaps not, but because of the syntax I'm using, it is necessary.  I've already upvoted David's answer.  This is just here as a possible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table").each(function(){
        $(this).find('TR:even').addClass("odd");
    });
});
```

Comment: Eh, no need for `.each()` here.

Answer (score 0):

This one processes rows relative to parent table, as opposed to the code you are using...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr:nth-child(even)").each(function() {
        $(this).addClass('odd');
    });
});
```